# Why do I get correct collisions when I don't use for loop, but when I use for loop only 1 object has collisions?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

So, let me be clear, I'm a beginner. I was trying to do some collision and decided to use for loop for multiple objects.

```
switch(quest){

    case 1:
        Swords = collectables.create(Game.width / 2 - 300, Game.height / 2, 'sword')
        Swords.body.immovable = true
        break

    case 2:
        for(let i = 0; i < 2; i++){
            Swords = collectables.create(Game.width/ 2 - 20, Game.height / 2, 'sword')
            Swords.body.immovable = true
        }
        break
}
```

And the first sword works perfectly fine, but when I switch to the second "quest" and use the for loop only 1 sword has collisions, what is a possible fix, thank you!

Link for the full code - https://pastebin.com/Nmh6PVkg

Comment: Please see how to create a [mre].

Comment: What do you mean by collisions?

Comment: @phuzi ```Game.physics.arcade.collide(player, ground)
   Game.physics.arcade.collide(player, enemy1, NPCint)
   Game.physics.arcade.collide(player, Swords, swordAdd)```

Comment: Little update - removed the for loop, the problem remains

Comment: I'm not familiar with Phaser, but could you be overwriting the Swords variable on each iteration of the for loop? Should Swords be an array with the code pushing new items into it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was resolved! Forgot to put the expresses in the brackets on the function.